# StringTokenizer and token 'space'

Tags: token, space, stringtokenizer

I have a question!
I am using StringTokenizer but I don't understand how i can take 'space' as a token!
this is an example of my method:

```
import java.util.*;

public class miaProva{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Write phrase");
    String s=sc.next();
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s, " ,.");
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('>');
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        sb.append(st.nextToken());
    }
    sb.append('<');
    System.out.println(sb);



}
}
```

but when it finds 'space' it interrupts the execution of the method.

INPUT:
1) `hi,how,are.you`
2) `hi,how are you`

OUTPUT:
1) `>hihowareyou<`
2) `>hihow<`

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried split method in the String class ?

In your sample, when you do sc.next(), it gives you the text separated by space.
So when you type "Hi,how you are" the sc.next() returns only "hi,how"
Its not a problem with StringTokenizer, use sc.nextLine() instead of sc.next(). That should give you the result you are epecting.

Comment: no, but I want to understand how to do this with StringTokenizer! 
my professor uses StringTokenizer in the same way as mine

Comment: Use sc.nextLine() instead of sc.next()

Comment: thank you very much. I didn't know this, I thought they were the same thing. Now I will study in deep this.
thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is using white space as its default delimiter. So when you call `sc.next()`, it only returns the first part of the input before the space. you can tell it to include the whole line like this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter("\r\n");
```

where "\r\n" matches *newline* on a Windows OS.

*edit:* It is better to use the `lineSeparator` method, so that is will work on any operating system.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
```

*edit 2:* Or better still (having read @Sathiesh's answer), use `sc.nextLine()`.